# Randomly swapping instance objects from one list to another

Tags: python, object

I think I need help with my code, I can't tell what the error is or where to fix it.  The following are a number of classes that handle a basic deck of playing cards and what it's suppose to do is randomly pick cards from the deck object and put them in the hand object, and then delete the objects from the hand object, so that the next hand I create won't pick up duplicates.  Maybe this is an obtuse way of thinking about it, but it seemed to be the best way of managing a deck of cards as it would be in the real world.

The problem is either in the logging method, or in the create_hand() method.  When I look at my hand after I run my code, I see the cards in my hand are still in the deck, if I go to the report in the log.  Instead, there are different cards that have been removed.  It reports the right number of cards taken out of the deck, but it also only reports that hearts are taken out in the tallies that count the number of cards according to suit.  However, my hand has a random assortment of unique cards, with unique values and suits.  So that part works.

```
class Suit(Enum):
    HEARTS = "Hearts"
    CLUBS = "Clubs"
    DIAMONDS = "Diamonds"
    SPADES = "Spades"

class Card:
    def __init__(self, suit, value):

        self.suit = suit
        self.value = value
        if self.suit == 1:
            self.suit = Suit.HEARTS
        elif self.suit == 2:
            self.suit = Suit.CLUBS
        elif self.suit == 3:
            self.suit = Suit.DIAMONDS
        else:
            self.suit = Suit.SPADES

    #and a host of magic methods that are irrelevant


class Deck:
    def __init__(self, deck_size):
        self.deck_size = deck_size
        self.deck = []
        card_suit = 1
        card_value = 2
        while len(self.deck) < self.deck_size:
            self.deck.append(Card(suit=card_suit, value=card_value))
            card_value += 1
            if card_value > 14:
                card_suit += 1
                card_value = 2

    def log_deck(self):
        logging.info("Deck cards: {}".format(len(self.deck)))
        hearts = clubs = diamonds = spades = 0
        for card in self.deck:
            if card.suit == Suit.HEARTS:
                hearts += 1
            elif card.suit == Suit.CLUBS:
                clubs += 1
            elif card.suit == Suit.DIAMONDS:
                diamonds += 1
            else:
                spades += 1
            logging.info("{} |".format(str(card)))
        logging.info("Hearts: {}, Clubs: {}, Diamonds: {}, Spades: {}".format(hearts, clubs, diamonds, spades))
        logging.info("*"*20)


class Hand:

    def __init__(self, size=2):
        self.size = size
        self.cards = []

    def create_hand(self, deck):
        self.cards = []
        while len(self.cards) < self.size:
            card = random.sample(deck.deck_cards, k=1)
            card_value = card[0].value
            card_suit = card[0].suit
            if card not in self.cards:
                self.cards.append(card)
                for card in deck.deck_cards:
                    if card.value == card_value and card.suit == card_suit:
                        deck.deck_cards.remove(card)
        deck.log_deck()
        return self.cards
```

And here's a sample of what the log looks like.  For conciseness I cut out most of the cards from the listing:

```
INFO:root:Deck cards: 47
INFO:root:|2 of Hearts| |
INFO:root:|3 of Hearts| |
INFO:root:|5 of Hearts| |
INFO:root:|6 of Hearts| |
....
INFO:root:|King of Spades| |
INFO:root:|Ace of Spades| |
INFO:root:Hearts: 8, Clubs: 13, Diamonds: 13, Spades: 13
INFO:root:********************
```

The tallies at the bottom seem to always show that there are only eight hearts after a hand was generated, even if my hand doesn't have hearts, and even if the cards that are missing aren't hearts.

Essentially, I can't figure out if my log is logging things incorrectly, or if I'm not removing cards correctly.  Or both.  Some testing with creating two hands using the same deck is showing duplicate cards, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your outer variable `card` is a `list` rather than a `Card` instance.

You append the `list` containing one item (your sampled card) to your `self.cards` list, rather than the item itself. I believe that is causing some disruption trying to remove the card in your last line.

I recommend changing `card` to `card[0]` in

```
if card not in self.cards
```

and

```
self.cards.append(card)
```

to see if that fixes the issue.

Moreover, you seem to be sampling from `deck.deck_cards`; I assume `deck` is a `Deck` object, but your given `Deck` implementation does not seem to have a `deck_cards` attribute. I would imagine that would throw an `AttributeError`, though.

---

Also, to save yourself (and anyone reading your code) some undue confusion, maybe you would want to not overwrite the `card` variable name in your inner loop.

Comment: Deck does have a deck_cards attribute.  I actually wrote half this question yesterday, but didn't post it, and updated that attribute name in pycharm in the meanwhile.  Where it says "self.deck" in the Deck implementation it should say self.deck_cards.  I was trying to avoid where it was saying "deck.deck."  I forgot to update the code in this post when I came back at lunch to finish writing it.

And you're right about using the word "card" too much.  I'll fix that.

Your recommendation didn't change the output, but it did give me an idea where to start looking.

Comment: I've also noticed through testing, that my code only removes the cards if the card is of the Hearts suit.

Answer (score 0):

I got some help from /u/Zigity_Zagity at /r/learnpython at reddit.  A slight rewrite of my code, thanks to him:

```
    def create_hand(self, deck):
        self.cards = random.sample(deck.deck_cards, k=self.size)

        deck.deck_cards = [card for card in deck.deck_cards if card not in self.cards]

        deck.log_deck()
        return self.cards
```

And fixing the Card object's `__eq__` method:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.value == other and self.suit.value == other
```